# VW Golf IV Possible Engine Misfire

Tags: engine, vw, obd-ii, golf, misfire

I guess I better start with a few details on the car in question:

- VW Golf IV
- 20 valve V5 petrol engine (2.3L)
- ~80k miles on the clock

Now the problem, it feels to me as if the car is down on power, it seems to be a bit reluctant to accelerate at anything over than a leisurely pace lower down the rev range, and even when the revs pick up it doesn't feel like it once did, I appreciate that it isn't going to drive like new after 80k miles, but this power loss seemed to happen over a fairly short period of time, rather than a gradual decay. I have also experienced the car struggling on start-up, we have always had to apply some throttle when starting the car to prevent it from stalling immediately, but the revs seem to be bouncing slightly under where the car tends to idle and the car shakes slightly when this happens.

Both myself and the other driver have seen the engine check light come on, but for both of us it went away within ~24 hours. I scanned for codes and the only fault listed was:

> P0345 - Powertrain
>   Camshaft Position Sensor "A" Circuit (Bank 2)

After a little search it seemed that this fault code is a bit vague, and I couldn't find anyone with the same model car and the same code.

My question to you is would this fault code be consistent with the behaviour I have described? Are they any other tell-tale signs which I should be looking out for? And finally is it worth clearing the fault code to see if it reappears?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that your camshaft position sensor or crank angle sensor is faulty. Either because they are actually faulty, or there is a wiring problem. Clearing the code won't do much. The symptoms of a bad cam or crank sensor are usually rough idling, difficulty starting and misfiring. Which makes sense, because your ECU gets wrong information regarding the position of the pistons and therefore can't adjust ignition timing properly.

In my experience, it is more often the crank angle sensor rather than the camshaft position sensor.

Comment: Thank you Juann, guess I better get on the phone to my mechanic!

Comment: On a side note, do you know why engine check light would disappear, but the fault code would remain?

Comment: I don't really know that. I assume the ecu decides that after not seeing an error for a while, it turns off the light, but saves the error in memory because it's a relatively major error.

Comment: Exactly right. The ECU will store codes even though it doesn't see the issue for the period of time (whatever that length of time may be). Sure helps in diagnosing things, that's for sure. Even for minor codes it will store them. Only removed if you erase them or disconnect the power (battery or fuse) for a long enough time.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks for your comment, does the fact that the light currently isn't on indicate that the problem isn't currently occurring? If this is the case then there might be another problem.

Comment: Check the obvious things first. Crank angle sensors go bad all the time. And they first stop working intermittently before finally dying outright. It's not expensive to test and it's not expensive to replace.

Comment: Agree with @JuannStrauss. Many CEL's won't get triggered if the parameters of the problem don't line up with what the computer "views" as an issue. There may still be an issue, but isn't *quite* bad enough to show the code. I don't know whether this is the fact with your situation, but it could be. Do as Juann is suggesting. I would bet that is the best place to start.

Comment: My Subaru regularly throws a P0420 (catalyst system below threshold or something). It does this because I actually took out the catalytic converter it's moaning about, so the error is there all the time, but the light comes on only every now and then. When it does, I just press a button in Torque to make it go away again. Or I used to. I disabled the code using EcuFlash after a while.

Comment: Sadly I am not mechanically savvy enough to tackle this myself. I might clear the code and see if it comes back and talk to my mechanic. Thank you both for your input.

Comment: @Paulster2 (and Juann who I cannot tag): I went and cleared the fault code and took the car out for about half an hour to see if I could get it to reproduce the fault code. Scanned when I got back and nothing! The car felt better to drive, more responsive lower down the revs and seemed to accelerate at a higher rate than before. Is it possible that the ECU placed the car in some form of limp home/reduced output setting in response to the fault code? Or am I just going crazy

Comment: Yes, when the ECU finds a serious problem, it switches over to a low octane fuel map (called limp mode or safe mode). It uses more fuel and decreases ignition timing to prevent possible knocking (every petrolhead's worst nightmare). When the problem goes away, it will switch back to the normal map. When the problem pops up again, you'll get the bad performance again. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

have benefitted from the same. for mine I replaced the crankshaft sensor but there has been no change. planning on replacing the rarely faulty camshaft sensor